# expected values of distributions over applied functions

Tags: probability

Assume two distributions $p_1$ and $p_2$ over $F$, where $F$ is a set of functions from a set $X$ (no matter what $X$ s) to the set of non negative reals (or naturals if this simplifies the problem).

Assume there exist $x,y \in X$ with $x \neq y$ such that both inequalities below hold:

1. $\sum_{f \in F} p_1(f) \cdot f(x) \ge \sum_{f \in F} p_2(f) \cdot f(x)$
2. $\sum_{f \in F} p_1(f) \cdot f(y) \ge \sum_{f \in F} p_2(f) \cdot f(y)$

Can we infer the following inequality?

$\sum_{f \in F} p_1(f) \cdot f(x) \cdot f(y) \ge \sum_{f \in F} p_2(f) \cdot f(x) \cdot f(y)$

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not the case. We can simplify our problem by generalizing it in the following way :

> Let $(X_1, Y_1)$ and $(X_2, Y_2)$ be couples of non-negative random variables. Assume that $\mathbb{E}(X_1) \ge \mathbb{E}(X_2)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y_1) \ge \mathbb{E}(Y_2)$. Is it true that $\mathbb{E}(X_1 Y_1) \ge \mathbb{E}(X_2 Y_2)$?

We can get back to your setting by taking $(X_1, Y_1) = (f(x), f(y))$ under the distribution $p_1$, and $(X_2, Y_2) = (f(x), f(y))$ under the distribution $p_2$. Actually, the two problems are equivalent.

Let us take $X_2 = 1$ and $Y_2 = 1$ almost surely. Then, let us take $(X_1, Y_1) = (1/2, 3/2)$ with probability $1/2$ and $(3/2, 1/2)$ with probability $1/2$. Then :

$$\mathbb{E}(X_2 Y_2) = 1$$

and:

$$\mathbb{E}(X_1 Y_1) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{4} < \mathbb{E}(X_2 Y_2).$$